# eloquent with multiples tables data and relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have these 3 tables:

```
  Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->float('lat', 10,6);
            $table->float('lng', 10,6);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        });

Schema::create('company_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
});

Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});
```

Now, I want to have an eloquent query, where it will return an array (Not only one item) of companies, where the (for example)company_id=1 on company_clients table. Also, the city_id is suppose to return the name and not the id, using the cities table. I cannot imagine how to do it right now.
I made:

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cities';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];


    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'city_id', 'id');
    }
} 

class CompanyClients extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'company_clients';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'client_id',
    ];

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'address', 'lat', 'lng', 'city_id',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'clients', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City', 'city_id', 'id');
    }

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyClients', 'company_id', 'id');
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyClients', 'client_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

But, I'm missing the code in the controller. I tried:

```
$result = Company::leftJoin('company_clients', function($join) {
            $join->on('companies.id', '=', 'company_clients.company_id');
        })->where('company_clients.company_id', '=', 1 )->get();
```

or

```
    $result = Company::with(['clients' => function($q){
        $q->where('company_id', 1);
    }])->get();
```

but is not returning the correct result. What I'm missing?

Thanks!

EDITED:
I had found a way, but I'm not sure if is the best way to do it. Can someone please confirm?

```
    $result = Company::join('company_clients', function($join) {
        $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
        $join->on('companies.id', '=', 'company_clients.client_id')->where('company_clients.company_id', '=', $user->company_id );
    })->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'companies.city_id')->get(array('companies.*', 'cities.name'));
```

Comment: Start checking your schema: `$table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('companies');`. Shouldn't it reference the clients table?

Comment: It's the same table for "companies" and client, just because the data is exact the same. But, there is a relationship between the companies and I called one of the columns to be client_id, to show the one company can have more than 1 client, that is also a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CompanyClients::with('company.city', 'clients')->where('company_id', 1)->get();
```

Rename

> companies

relationship on the CompanyClients model to

> company

Comment: It's a good shot! 
The result is what I would expect, but the format of the json is weird:
http://pastebin.com/PaQRjd6t
I was expecting something like this:
http://pastebin.com/XCA26L4z

Once that is a demo, the result is the same in all the entries, so this is not wrong.

Comment: It would be much efficent if you get company separately. beacuse from above query it will query the company record for every clients. CompanyClients::with( 'clients')->where('company_id', $company_id)->get();  Company::with('city')->find($company_id); then you can format json according to your taste using stdClass

Comment: This is the part that I cannot understand. From CompanyClients, I need to run once to get all the entries that have company_id=1. After that, I just need to get the info from Companies table and in an almost separate call, get the name of the city in another table.
I cannot see why having one more table for clients would make it more efficient.
BTW, the code that I did above(In the edited part in the main question) is OK? I basically doing 2 inner joins and get the result. Not sure if is a good practice or not.

Comment: Something like this https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y7ctlps5fvMy00kwNg_BOt-kXFjZ7JmNQhwaVrgCzyc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yep this one got me a really good approach. In the end I modified a little, but your response was really helpful to make me achieve the end result. To be honest, I used the same approach in all the other parts of my project, because it's clear to understand what's happening. Thank you!